# For what platform should i compile my application so it can be available to others? 32bit or 64bit?

Tags: objective-c, macos, 32bit-64bit

I'm new to OS X world but i want to learn how to, and then build a Mac OS X application using Objective C and XCode.

What i don't know is for what platform should i compile this app so i can make it available to others. 
Do i compile it for 32bit or most of the Macs are 64bit now and i'm ok by compiling it for 64bit?

Comment: Just compile it as 32 bit unless you have a compelling reason to make it 64 bit - all platforms can run 32 bit but only some can run 64 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern Macs are all 64-bit now, but you can still compile your apps for 32-bit/64-bit so they will work on both platforms.

If you are learning and have no need for backwards compatibility I would stick to 64-bit. That way you get to use all the advantages of the modern runtime (only available on 64-bit), and ARC(only available on 64-bit).